# I canot find information what => means?

Tags: javascript

recently i found some operators in Javascript looks:

=>

.

I tried to look it up on Google, but cannot find any explanation. Is there someone who knows about this operator?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions

Comment: [SO docs: JavaScript Arrow function](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/5007/arrow-functions#t=201701061213278367458)

Comment: Or simply go on the [MDN page for operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) and search there.

Comment: An example of use is in **Arrow functions** https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called arrow function

You can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions

```
var a = [
  "Hydrogen",
  "Helium",
  "Lithium",
  "Beryl­lium"
];

var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });

var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );
```

Comment: Thanks, for example in D3.js:  `.attr("a", (d, i) => 12 + i * 3)`                     can be rewritten as                                                                               `.attr("a", function (d, i) {return (12 + i * 3)}` ??

Comment: Yes... but there a diference between 'this' scope when using arrow functions and the normal functions..be aware of that